# NSMutableArray addObject freezes my app

Tags: iphone, debugging

Tons of similar questions, but none of their answers seem to answer mine...

I'm creating my array as such:

```
imgArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
```

Later (in another function) I am trying to add an object to it:

```
Attachment newAttachment = [[[Attachment alloc] init] autorelease];
newAttachment.fileName = filename;
newAttachment.file = file;
[imgArray addObject:newAttachment];
```

This results in the iPhone app freezing up.  The simulator seems fine; the clock on the status bar keeps ticking, I don't get any error messages, but my app is no longer responding.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've tried commenting out just the last line, and the app runs fine when it's not there.

Comment: Could you post the Attachment .h and the code for the init method? My first though is that the object might be *really* large and you have a memory issue.

Comment: @Roger it's basically a wrapper for NSData but has a NSString that holds the filename.  I'm attaching small photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do

```
imgArray = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10] retain];
```

all class methods if return an object is returned with retain count 1 and object already in autorelease pool so if want to use that object beyond the current working block the you should always retain that object because then reference is lost outside the block.

Comment: This works!  I'll worry about the memory problems it causes when they happen.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are not retaining *imgArray*. Are you? Try,

```
imgArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10]
```

if not.

Comment: I'm really new to ObjC and have little experience with C, too, so I don't understand what that's supposed to do.  It doesn't seem to work (app fails to load with `...uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '***-[__NSPlaceHolderArray arrayWithCapacity:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3d05e40`